# Throw new TypeError('Request path contains unescaped characters')

Tags: node.js, typeerror

I get this error when I try to run my node js application:

> _http_client.js:127
>         throw new TypeError('Request path contains unescaped characters');
>         ^
>
> TypeError: Request path contains unescaped characters
>       at new ClientRequest (_http_client.js:127:13)
>       at Object.request (http.js:38:10)
>       at Object.exports.getDuration (/Users/paulcarron/git/integration-test-runner/modules/getEventLog.js:53:20)
>       at /Users/paulcarron/git/integration-test-runner/modules/jobRunningService.js:75:21
>       at IncomingMessage. (/Users/paulcarron/git/integration-test-runner/modules/getEventLog.js:35:13)
>       at emitNone (events.js:111:20)
>       at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:208:7)
>       at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:1056:12)
>       at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:138:11)
>       at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:180:9)

After some investigation I've concluded its because of the `+ myId` in getEventLog.js(see code at the very bottom of question). The entire script is called by this function in a different script:

```
child.stderr.on('data', function(uuid, data) {

  getEventLog.getId(uuid, function(err, id){
    if(err) return console.log(err)
    getEventLog.getDuration(id, function(err, duration){
        if(err) return console.log(err)
        jobLogger.info(escape(data) + "<br />");
    })
  });

});
```

I  thought there might have been a whitespace in myId so I added a `console.log("myId: " + myId)` and found that it returned `myId: [object Object]`. How do I fix this so that `myId` is an ID in a correct format?

```
var http = require("http");
var fs = require('fs');
var async = require('async');
var readline = require('readline')
//var db = require('./dbPool');

//get file name
var options =  {
    "method" : "GET",
    "hostname" : "127.0.0.1",
    "port" : "18080",
    "path" : "/api/v1/applications/"
};

exports.getId = function (uuid, callback) {
    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {

        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks));

            var arrFound = Object.keys(body).filter(function(key) {
                if (body[key].name.indexOf(uuid) > -1) { 
                    return body[key].name;
                }
            }).reduce(function(obj, key){
                obj = body[key].id;
                return obj;
            }, {});
            callback(null, arrFound);
        });
    });
    req.end();
}

exports.getDuration = function (myId, callback) {
    //getEventLog.getId(function(err, id){

    //get file name
    var options =  {
        "method" : "GET",
        "hostname" : "127.0.0.1",
        "port" : "18080",
        "path" : "/api/v1/applications/" + myId
    };

    var req = http.request(options, function (res) {
        console.log(options)

        var chunks = [];

        res.on("data", function (chunk) {
            chunks.push(chunk);
        });

        res.on("end", function () {
            var body = JSON.parse(Buffer.concat(chunks));

            var attempts = body.attempts

            var arrFound = Object.keys(body).filter(function(key) {

                return attempts[0].duration;

            }).reduce(function(obj, key){
                obj = body.attempts[0].duration;
                return obj;
            }, {});
            //console.log(arrFound);
            callback(null, arrFound);
        });
    });
    req.end();
 //   })
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here was that myId was a JSON object rather than a string. This meant that a html page was returned tather than the JSON location I required.